# fetching different values from the same column when only one value is known

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following table

```
     +-----+-------+
     |col 1| col 2 |
     +-----+-------+
     |   a |   b   |
     |   b |   a   |
     |   a |   d   |
     |   c |   b   |
```

i know the value of a, now i want to use that value to run a query to fetch the id where a = b and where b = a... i expect the result to be

```
     +-----+-------+
     |col 1| col 2 |
     +-----+-------+
     |   a |   b   |
     |   b |   a   |
```

thanks

Comment: "where a = b and where b = a;" `a` and `b` are not column names. You need to clarify the problem statement further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(col1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,col2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(col1,col2)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('a','b'),
('b','a'),
('a','d'),
('c','b');

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.col1 = x.col2 
   AND y.col2 = x.col1 
 WHERE 'a' IN (x.col1,x.col2);
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| b    | a    |
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Writing the `Where` clause, where b = a and a = b, is practically the same. Use this example, if a = 5, and b = 5.

b = a means 5 = 5,
a = b means 5 = 5

I think its both the same. Running the query below should give you want need:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `col1` = `col2` AND `col1` = a;
```

Comment: Where do you see in the expected output, that both the columns have same value ?

Comment: From the question, if b = a or a = b. It is simply filtering for results, with the same value under both columns where one of the column is a

Answer (score -1):

this will work:

```
    select * from d061_1;

        a   b
        b   a
        a   d
        c   b
    select m.* from d061_1 m ,d061_1 n where m.col2=n.col1 and m.col1=n.col2;
    output:
    b   a
    a   b
```